# Script stops immediatly if variable is not defined in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, undefined, userscripts, tampermonkey

Using the Tampermonkey extension in Chrome, my script will fail to execute as soon as a variable is undefined. I've tried using an `if` conditional but the console just spits out the "ERROR! Execution of script..." message as soon as it reads the variable.

The variable is undefined because, using `JSON.parse`, it grabs a value that exists in another part of the website. I would like to make it so it avoids this undefined variable and continues with the rest of the script instead of stopping right after failing to get the value.

Example:

We have variable 1 and variable 2 in website.com/test1.html

The script runs fine and outputs the value of both variables.

However, website.com/test2.html only has the value that variable 2 is assigned to, but the value of variable 1 is non-existent.

The script stops executing as soon as this is detected and Chrome's console outputs it was undefined, but fails to provide the value of variable 2.

How can I work around this?

Comment: Check to see if the variable is defined first?

Answer (score -1):

You can use following condition 
if(typeof variable1 === "undefined")

Comment: I already tried this. The problem is that Chrome stops executing the script as soon as it finds that the variable is undefined EVEN if there's a conditional below it that indicates what to do if that happens.

Comment: Can you share the code snippet?